# Php recursion to get all possibilities of strings

Tags: php, recursion

Here is my code to get all possibilities:

```
$seq[1] = 'd';
$seq[2] = 'f';
$seq[3] = 'w';
$seq[4] = 's';

for($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++)
{
    $s['length_1'][] = $seq[$i];
    $c1++;

    for($i2 = $i+1; $i2 < 5; $i2++)
    {
        $s['length_2'][] = $seq[$i].$seq[$i2]; 
        $last = $seq[$i].$seq[$i2]; 
        $c2++;

        for($i3 = $i2+1; $i3 < 5; $i3++)
        { 
            $s['length_3'][] = $last.$seq[$i3];
            $last = $last.$seq[$i3];    
            $c3++;

            for($i4 = $i3+1; $i4 < 5; $i4++)
            {
                $s['length_4'][] = $last.$seq[$i4];   
                $c4++;  
            }
        }
    }
}

for($i = 0; $i < $c1; $i++)
    echo $s['length_1'][$i].'<br>'; 

for($i = 0; $i < $c2; $i++)
    echo $s['length_2'][$i].'<br>';   

for($i = 0; $i < $c3; $i++)
    echo $s['length_3'][$i].'<br>';  

for($i = 0; $i < $c4; $i++)
    echo $s['length_4'][$i].'<br>';
```

But if I want to add more, then I will have to add one more loop. So, how can I do it with recursion? I try, I try, but I really can't do it.
Please help and post example as simple as possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a simple algo. Iterate from 1 to 2<sup>count(array)</sup>-1. On each iteration, if j-th bit in a binary representation of the loop counter is equal to 1, include j-th element in a combination.

As PHP needs to be able to calculate 2<sup>count(array)</sup> as an integer, this may never exceed `PHP_INT_MAX`. On a 64-bit PHP installation your array cannot have more than 62 elements, as 2<sup>62</sup> stays below `PHP_INT_MAX` while 2<sup>63</sup> exceeds it.

EDIT: This computes all possible combinations, not permutations (ie, 'abc' = 'cba'). It does so by representing the original array in binary and "counting up" from 0 to the binary representation of the full array, effectively building a list of every possible unique combination.

```
$a = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');

$len  = count($a);
$list = array();

for($i = 1; $i < (1 << $len); $i++) {
    $c = '';
    for($j = 0; $j < $len; $j++)
        if($i & (1 << $j))
            $c .= $a[$j];
    $list[] = $c;
}

print_r($list);
```

Comment: this won't test all possibilities..
for example if only going for [a, b] it will output this: a
b
ab what about "ba"?

Comment: "ba" is same as "ab" in term of combinations or sets. What you looking for is permutations.

Comment: @evening http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Comment: i got a memory error when i use your code with `$a = range('A', 'Z');`, the code of @KemalDağ below works fine.

Answer (score 22):

One algorithm is here,

```
function getCombinations($base,$n){

$baselen = count($base);
if($baselen == 0){
    return;
}
    if($n == 1){
        $return = array();
        foreach($base as $b){
            $return[] = array($b);
        }
        return $return;
    }else{
        //get one level lower combinations
        $oneLevelLower = getCombinations($base,$n-1);

        //for every one level lower combinations add one element to them that the last element of a combination is preceeded by the element which follows it in base array if there is none, does not add
        $newCombs = array();

        foreach($oneLevelLower as $oll){

            $lastEl = $oll[$n-2];
            $found = false;
            foreach($base as  $key => $b){
                if($b == $lastEl){
                    $found = true;
                    continue;
                    //last element found

                }
                if($found == true){
                        //add to combinations with last element
                        if($key < $baselen){

                            $tmp = $oll;
                            $newCombination = array_slice($tmp,0);
                            $newCombination[]=$b;
                            $newCombs[] = array_slice($newCombination,0);
                        }

                }
            }

        }

    }

    return $newCombs;


}
```

I know it is not efficent in any way, but using in small sets should not be a problem

first base parameter is an array containing elements to be considered when generating combinations.

for simple usage and output:

```
var_dump(getCombinations(array("a","b","c","d"),2));
```

and output is

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string 'a' (length=1)
      1 => string 'b' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string 'a' (length=1)
      1 => string 'c' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array
      0 => string 'a' (length=1)
      1 => string 'd' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array
      0 => string 'b' (length=1)
      1 => string 'c' (length=1)
  4 => 
    array
      0 => string 'b' (length=1)
      1 => string 'd' (length=1)
  5 => 
    array
      0 => string 'c' (length=1)
      1 => string 'd' (length=1)
```

To list all subsets of an array, using this combinations algorithm just execute

```
$base =array("a","b","c","d");

for($i = 1; $i<=4 ;$i++){
    $comb = getCombinations($base,$i);

    foreach($comb as $c){
        echo implode(",",$c)."<br />";
    }

}
```

And output is

```
a
b
c
d
a,b
a,c
a,d
b,c
b,d
c,d
a,b,c
a,b,d
a,c,d
b,c,d
a,b,c,d
```

Comment: In a list like 

Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 14
    [3] => 39
    [4] => 39
    [5] => 39
    [6] => 39
    [7] => 40
    [8] => 40
    [9] => 42
    [10] => 42
    [11] => 45
)


How can I create permutations like

10, 10, 14

and not just

10, 14, 39?

Answer (score 5):

Here it is:

```
<?php
function combinations($text,$space)
{
    // $text is a variable which will contain all the characters/words of which  we want to make all the possible combinations
    // Let's make an array which will contain all the characters
    $characters=explode(",", $text);
    $x=count($characters);

    $comb = fact($x);

    // In this loop we will be creating all the possible combinations of the  positions that are there in the array $characters

    for ($y=1; $y<= $comb; $y++)
    {
        $ken = $y-1;
        $f = 1;
        $a = array();
        for($iaz=1; $iaz<=$x; $iaz++)
            {
                $a[$iaz] = $iaz;
                $f = $f*$iaz;
            }
        for($iaz=1; $iaz<=$x-1; $iaz++)
            {
                $f = $f/($x+1-$iaz);
                $selnum = $iaz+$ken/$f;
                $temp = $a[$selnum];
                for($jin=$selnum; $jin>=$iaz+1; $jin--)
                    {
                        $a[$jin] = $a[$jin-1];
                    }
                $a[$iaz] = $temp;
                $ken = $ken%$f;
            }
        $t=1;

           // Let’s start creating a word combination: we have all the  necessary positions
        $newtext="";

        // Here is the while loop that creates the word combination
        while ($t<=$x)
            {
                $newtext.=$characters[$a[$t]-1]."$space";
                $t++;
            }
        $combinations[] =  $newtext ;
    }

        return $combinations;

}

function fact($a){
if ($a==0) return 1;
else return $fact = $a * fact($a-1);
}

$a = combinations("d,f,w,s","");
    foreach ($a as $v) {
            echo "$v"."\n";
    }

?>
```

**Output:**

```
dfws
dfsw
dwfs
dwsf
dsfw
dswf
fdws
fdsw
fwds
fwsd
fsdw
fswd
wdfs
wdsf
wfds
wfsd
wsdf
wsfd
sdfw
sdwf
sfdw
sfwd
swdf
swfd
```

---

Also, [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n);

Comment: uses a lot of memory :/ "PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in..."

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
function combinations($arr) {
    $combinations = array_fill(0, count($arr)+1, array());
    $combinations[0] = array('');
    for ($i = 0, $n = count($arr); $i < $n; ++$i) {
        for ($l = $n-$i; $l > 0; --$l) {
            $combinations[$l][] = implode('', array_slice($arr, $i, $l));
        }
    }
    return $combinations;
}
```

Here’s an example:

```
$arr = array('d', 'f', 'w', 's');
var_dump(combinations($arr));
```

This produces the following array:

```
array(
    array(''),                 // length=0
    array('d', 'f', 'w', 's'), // length=1
    array('df', 'fw', 'ws'),   // length=2
    array('dfw', 'fws'),       // length=3
    array('dfws')              // length=4
)
```

A brief explanation:

> For each *i* with 0 ≤ *i* < *n*, get all sub-arrays *arr*‍[*i*,‍*i*+‍*l*] with each possible length of 0 < *l* ≤ *n* - *i*.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my function to print all possible character combinations:

```
function printCombinations($var, $begin = 0, $preText = "") {
    for($i = $begin; $i < count($var); $i++) {
        echo $preText . $var[$i] . "\n";
        if(($i+1) < count($var))
            printCombinations($var, $i+1, $preText . $var[$i]);
    }
}

printCombinations(array('a','b','c','d','e'));
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another way to do it in codeigniter/php.

```
`function recursiveCombinations($var,$n = '') {
    $len = count($var);
    if ($n == 0){
        return array(array());
    }
   $arr = [];
   for ($i = 0;$i<$len;$i++){
       $m = $var[$i];
       $remLst = array_slice($var, $i + 1); 
       $remainlst_combo = $this->recursiveCombinations($remLst, $n-1);
       foreach ($remainlst_combo as $key => $val){
       array_push($arr,array_merge(array($m),$val));
       }
}
return $arr;
}

    $arr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','l','m','n','o','p'];
    $n = $this->recursiveCombinations($arr,5);`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I know, it's very old topic, but I found it as a nice challenge for myself and made more readable and pure recursive function for the goal.

```
getCombinations(array $base, int $n): array {
    if ($n == 0) {
        return [[]];
    }

    if (empty($base)) {
        return [];
    }

    // Get the first element from the base array.
    $firstElement = array_shift($base);

    // Get the combinations with the first element.
    $combinationsWithFirst = getCombinations($base, $n - 1);
    array_walk($combinationsWithFirst, function (&$combination) use ($firstElement) {
        array_unshift($combination, $firstElement);
    });

    // Get the combinations without the first element.
    $combinationsWithoutFirst = getCombinations($base, $n);

    // Merge both combinations and return.
    return array_merge($combinationsWithFirst, $combinationsWithoutFirst);
}
```

Then `getCombinations(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2)` will output

```
array:6 [
    0 => array:2 [
        0 => "a"
        1 => "b"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
        0 => "a"
        1 => "c"
    ]
    2 => array:2 [
        0 => "a"
        1 => "d"
    ]
    3 => array:2 [
        0 => "b"
        1 => "c"
    ]
    4 => array:2 [
        0 => "b"
        1 => "d"
    ]
    5 => array:2 [
        0 => "c"
        1 => "d"
    ]
]
```