# Where can I find a combinations algorithm(nCr) in PHP?

Tags: php, algorithm, combinations

By combinations algorithm I mean code that will produce output similar to the example below.

I found the C implementation by Knuth already but it used the "goto" statement. PHP 5.2.4 (the version of PHP I must use) does not support "goto".  So when I port it to PHP it will error on the goto statments.  I could modify it further but I think I might loose efficiency.

Or if not a PHP implementation perhaps an implementation that is not too object-oriented(so that the actual algorithm is not hidden) or an implementation that does not use "goto".

Example:
nCr, n=3, r=2

3C2 =

{1,2},{1,3},{2,3}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279722/php-recursion-to-get-all-possibilities-of-strings) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742506/php-array-combinations) some solutions.

Comment: I went with the Chase algorithm in C and converted to PHP.  It does not use "goto".