# PHP, make with all other array values

Tags: php, arrays, function, combiners

I have to make a complex array with other array values.

The original array is:

```
Array (
     [0] => Array (
        [0] => A
        [1] => B
        [2] => C
    )

    [1] => Array (
        [0] => D
        [1] => E
        [2] => F
    )
)
```

I'm looking for a function which give me all combinations values possible, like this:

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (A, D),
  [1] => Array (A, E),
  [2] => Array (A, F),
  [3] => Array (B, D),
  [4] => Array (B, E),
  [5] => Array (B, F),
  [6] => Array (C, D),
  [7] => Array (C, E),
  [8] => Array (C, F)
)
```

Of course, this algo must work even if the numbers of values in the original array are different.

I'm looking for a simple function in PHP documentation for doing this, but I did not find one.

I've Googled it with keywords like "multiplex" or "combine" but with no luck. I think the best way is to make a recursive function, but I can't find the correct algo.

Comment: basically you want a cartesian result. here is a link for a similiar example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311779/finding-cartesian-product-with-php-associative-arrays

Comment: will you be constantly having 3 values in the child array??

Comment: hi, and tks for your answer. No, my original array could have X entries with arrays

Comment: You could take all the elements from the sub-arrays and create a temporary array with all the elements, and use my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/27177761/3186769 to find all 2-element combinations. Does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple recursive function to calculate cartesian product:

```
function cartesian(array $data)
{
    function cartesian_r(array $data, array $path, &$out)
    {
        if (count($data) > 1) {
            // recursive step
            $head = array_slice($data, 0, -1);
            $tail = end($data);
            foreach ($tail as $item) {
                cartesian_r($head, array_merge($path, [$item]), $out);
            }
        } else {
            // unwind step
            foreach ($data[0] as $item) {
                $out[] = array_merge([$item], $path);
            }
        }
    }

    $out = [];
    cartesian_r($data, [], $out);

    return $out;
}

$out = cartesian([['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F']]);

print_r($out);
```

#### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => E
            [2] => C
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => B
            [1] => E
            [2] => C
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => E
            [2] => D
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => B
            [1] => E
            [2] => D
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => F
            [2] => C
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => B
            [1] => F
            [2] => C
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => F
            [2] => D
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => B
            [1] => F
            [2] => D
        )

)
```

Comment: This one is nice, +1. However, `[]` is not supported on pre 5.4, it can be easily replaced with `array()`, and it works just as well: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/jdct-q0uf

Comment: @TiborB you should be using php 5.4 already  ;)

Comment: PHP 5.3 is EOL and no longer supported, deal with it before it deals with you :)

Comment: I'm usually dealing with 5.4+, but apparently, PHPFiddle is still 5.3.29 :/

Comment: @TiborB. I've never used phpfiddle before; I use either eval.in or 3v4l.

Comment: Many thanks to Jack!! It's the good function.

Answer (score 2):

Just two foreach

```
$first = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
$second = array('E', 'F', 'G');

$result = array();
foreach ($first as $f) {
    foreach ($second as $s) {
        $result[] = array($f, $s);
    }
}
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Thks but I don't know the number of sub arrays. So in case of more than 2 sub arrays, your code will not work.

Comment: And what if there is a third? What should be the output then?

Comment: Simple, then each output element contains three elements.

Comment: And all of those combinations? Then it's a littlebit harder, but with a recursive functions it could be done.

Comment: Yup, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27547925/1338292) :)

Answer (score 1):

This works for as many sub_arrays as you wont .. it is not ordered as the original output but this can be easily fixed with a sort function as in the example:

```
 $input = array(
    0 => array ('A','B','C'),
    1 => array ('D','E','F'),
    2 => array ('X','Y','Z'),
    /*...*/
);

$result = array();  
foreach($input as $sub_arr){
    $_result = array();
    foreach($sub_arr as $val){
        if($result){
            foreach($result as $old){
                $old[] = $val;
                $_result[] = $old;
            }
        }else{ 
            $_result[] = array($val);
        }
    }
    $result = $_result;
} 
array_multisort($result); //sort all layers alphabetically.
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Working example: [Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/vhm6-jebn)

Comment: I think this one deserves an upvote for simulating a recursion without a recursive function.

Comment: It solves the task...and it is not necessary to use recursion. (Except it is a homework task).

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest dynamic thing i could imagine :

It displays "ALL COMBINATIONS POSSIBLE"

```
<?php

$origArray = array(
    array(
         "A",
         "B",
         "C"        
    ),
     array(
        "D",
        "E",
        "F"     
    )
);

$endArray = array();

foreach ($origArray as $key_1 => $value_1){
    foreach ($origArray as $key_2 => $value_2){
        if($key_1 == $key_2){
            continue;
        }
        foreach($value_1 as $key_1_1 => $value_1_1 ){
            foreach ($value_2 as $key_2_1 => $value_2_1){
                $endArray[] = array($value_1_1, $value_2_1);
            }
        }


    }

}
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($endArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

If you want to dispaly all combinations of the firts sub-array you could use:

```
<?php

$origArray = array(
    array(
         "A",
         "B",
         "C"        
    ),
     array(
        "D",
        "E",
        "F"     
    )
);

$endArray = array();

foreach ($origArray as $key_1 => $value_1){
    foreach($origArray[0] as $key_1_1 => $value_1_1 ){
        if($key_1 == 0 ){
            continue;
        }
        foreach ($value_1 as $key_2_1 => $value_2_1){

            $endArray[] = array($value_1_1, $value_2_1);
        }
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($endArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: `echo count($endArray) // 18`

Comment: seconed example == 9 , but not ALL COMBINATIONS, but rather ALL COMBINATIONS with first sub-array

Comment: OP forgot to mention that the array could contain more than two elements.

Comment: yeap, and this code(s) will still work then.

Comment: It works in the sense that it doesn't crash, but the expected output of an input array with three elements should be sets of three.